# Optional Title in Creating Hyperlink does not work

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks, editor

Optional Title in Creating Hyperlink does not work, or at least not as expected.

[image: Insert Hyperlink Dialog]

If I click ok, the following markup is rendered:

```
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://google.de "Hello Google"
```

> [image]

I expected:

```
[Hello Google][1]
[1]: http://google.de
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My bad.

The *optional title* is actually the `HTML` title, e. g. tooltip. I just learned it is possible to write tooltips in markdown.

Therefore, it isn't actually a bug, but IMHO it is still [bad user experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368274/2441442). Especially for new Users who are new to markdown.

Comment: Why not convert to a feature request to improve the UX?

Comment: [see this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368274/2441442) @jpmc26

Answer (score 1):

I would support changing the text to "optional hovertext."

Comment: hovertext? You mean tooltip?